# Pandas: Replace and remove character in columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe in pandas, in this format:
I need to perform formatting on my dataframe that is larger than this, generally speaking only on the 'CTe' column

```
CTe = ["1221-2","12321-45","123-3"]
UF = ['A','B','C']

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data = zip(CTe,UF),
        columns=["CTe","UF"])
```

And I would like to know how I can format the entire "CTe" column, where I can remove the '-' and the numbers after the '-'. The result I expect is the following:

```
CTe = ["1221","12321","123"]
UF = ['A','B','C']

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data = zip(CTe,UF),
        columns=["CTe","UF"])
```

I'm asking this because I just need to do a "merge" and my other dataframe only has the number that is before the ' - '.

I don't know what I can do

Comment: Would you still want to be able to do the merge while keeping the original string?

Comment: I would like to replace the 'cte' values ​​of the original df, with the string

Comment: I understand that, but my question was regarding the merge, can you give an example of the merge you want to perform?

Comment: @mozway I would like to place the values ​​of an entire column of the DataFrame, for example:

Co = ["A","B","C"]
Ce = [1,2,3]

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data = zip(Co,Ce),
        columns=["Co","Ce"])

I would like to know what code I can use to make pandas "print" the values ​​of the Co column like this:

A,B,C

Put values ​​in a column in a comma-separated list only. So that I can copy and paste these values ​​into my work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
df['CTe'].str.split('-', 1).str[0]
```

Alternatively clean the CTe list before creating the dataframe:

```
CTe_cleaned = [''.join(x.split('-')[0]) for x in CTe ]
```

Comment: Yes, how can I replace this function in my column to show the result?

Comment: The first option works, but I would like to know how I can apply it to a new dataframe copy of my original df, putting these new values?

Comment: Not sure if I am following what you mean, this?:
`df_copy = df.copy()`
`df_copy['CTe'] = df_copy['CTe'].str.split('-', 1).str[0]`

Comment: I would like to put the result of the formula you mentioned "df['CTe'].str.split('-', 1).str[0]", in my Df

Comment: See my previous comment.